# How to search in array with in an array in couchbase query

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have a document having nested structure like given below

```
{

"docType": "account",
"accounts": [
    {
        "id": "123123",
        "name": "abcdCompany",
        "owner": "abcdCompany corporation",
        "email": "abcdCompany1234@heman.com",
        "projects": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "abcdCompany asset management",
                "owner": "assetMgmt",
                "email": "assetMgmt@heman.com"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "abcdCompany alert notification",
                "owner": "alertNotification",
                "email": "alertNotification@heman.com"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

How we can get project having "owner": "alertNotification"

Comment: Have you looked into CouchDB views?

Comment: @Rishabh are you using Couchbase or are you using CouchDB? They are not the same, so the answer will be very different. If you are using Couchbase, do you want to use N1QL?

Comment: @MatthewGroves its Couchbase, yes if you suggest both type of queries with and without N1QL

Comment: Are you using spring data couchbase? The tag has been removed.

Comment: Sorry, I removed it, because this question didn't seem related to spring. Feel free to add it back if it's relevant!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not exactly sure what you have in mind (you may want to [check out this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55833063/when-should-i-use-unnest-vs-any-satisfies-in-n1ql) for details about [`UNNEST`](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/unnest.html) vs [`ANY/SATISFIES`](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/indexing-arrays.html#query-predicate-format)), but if you want to just select the nested project objects where owner == 'alertNotification', you can use `UNNEST`. You've got an array within an array, so you'd need to `UNNEST` twice:

```
SELECT prj.*
FROM moviegame b
UNNEST b.accounts acct
UNNEST acct.projects prj
WHERE prj.owner == 'alertNotification';
```

That would return:

```
[
  {
    "email": "alertNotification@heman.com",
    "id": "2",
    "name": "abcdCompany alert notification",
    "owner": "alertNotification"
  }
]
```

If you DON'T want to UNNEST, and you just want to return any document which has an account which has a project which has an 'owner' of 'alertNotification', then you can use `ANY/SATISFIES` (again nested, because there's an array within an array):

```
SELECT b.*
FROM moviegame b
WHERE ANY a IN accounts SATISFIES (ANY p IN a.projects SATISFIES p.owner == 'alertNotification' END) END
```

which would return the whole document in your sample (below) but would NOT include other documents that do NOT have a project with owner=='alertNotification' within them:

```
[
  {
    "accounts": [
      {
        "email": "abcdCompany1234@heman.com",
        "id": "123123",
        "name": "abcdCompany",
        "owner": "abcdCompany corporation",
        "projects": [
          {
            "email": "assetMgmt@heman.com",
            "id": "1",
            "name": "abcdCompany asset management",
            "owner": "assetMgmt"
          },
          {
            "email": "alertNotification@heman.com",
            "id": "2",
            "name": "abcdCompany alert notification",
            "owner": "alertNotification"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "docType": "account"
  }
]
```